# GET() communication between Angular and Node JS

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, api

I have an Angular and Node JS project with Typescript in which I am trying to create the communication between them using a service.

When making a get() request from the front I can't get anything from the back, I don't know what I might be missing to configure or what problem I have in the service.

This is the API response:

[image]

This is the service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class DashboardService {

  private url = 'http://localhost:8080/list/product'

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
  ) {}

  public getTest() {
    return this.http.get(`${this.url}`);
  }
}
```

This is the component.ts where I am trying to display the message on the console:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DashboardService } from './dashboard.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.scss']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private dashboardService: DashboardService
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('hola')
    console.log(this.dashboardService.getTest().subscribe())
  }
}
```

This is what I get on the console:

[image]

How should I do the GET() request to communicate with the back?

Comment: You're logging the object returned by subscribing to the endpoint, not the data returned by the call to the endpoint. Try `this.dashboardService.getTest().subscribe(res => console.log(res));` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are subscribing but then doing nothing with the subscription. I recomment you read up on angular subscriptions a bit more, but effectively what you want to do is get the result from the subscription like so.

```
items: string[];

this.dashboardService.getTest().subscribe({
     next: result => items = result,
});
```

Also your get method in your service needs a bit of work.

```
  public getTest(): Observable<string[]> {
    return this.http.get<string[]>(`${this.url}`);
  }
```

This is for returning a list of strings

Comment: Okay, I was reading the subscribe information now, thanks. Another question about the service, what type should the request have? That is, the get() method is going to return a string, it is recommended to make the get() request: return this.http.get<string>(`${this.url}`); or it can be left like this now (return this.http.get(`${this.url}`);)

Comment: It depends what you want to return, Ive assumed you are returning a list of products names for my example. If you are returning a list of project objects, you will need to create an interface, and make items a variable of that interface, and observe that instead of an array of strings